# How to warn for duplicate entry vba

Tags: excel, vba, forms, duplicates, countif

I have here a code from a vba form that is supposed to warn if 2 conditions are met (coded in Submit button):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rangeID As Long, rangeName As String

rangeID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(ws.Range("A:A"), idField.Value)
rangeName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(ws.Range("B:B"), nameField.Value)

If rangeID >= 1 And rangeName >=  1 Then
MsgBox, "You already have entered this parent."
Else
'Save to excel sheet
End If
```

Now, let's say in the sheet, there is an existing:

```
ID      NAME 
1110    Michael
```

When I enter `1110 for ID` and `Annie for Name`, it should save in the sheet. However, the warn prompts.

```
You already have entered this parent.
```

When I enter `1111 for ID` and `Annie for Name`, the warn also prompts.

```
You already have entered this parent.
```

This is a small system that enters the ID number of a parent and the name of his/her child/children in a class.

For a parent with 2 kids, the output should be:

```
ID      NAME 
1110    Michael
1110    Annie
```

If added with another parent with 1 kid having the same name of the previous entry, it should be like this:

```
ID      NAME 
1110    Michael
1110    Annie
1111    Annie
```

The last output is that, it should/must never save 2 same ID and 2 same Name.

```
ID      NAME 
1110    Michael
1111    Annie   
1111    Annie (it should not be saved to sheet)
```

What could I miss in my code? TY

Comment: The issue with your code could be that you're checking the conditions for rangeID and rangeName independently. This means that if there's any occurrence of the ID in column A and any occurrence of the Name in column B (even if they're not on the same row), the warning will be triggered. One way to do this is by using a loop to check each row in the range.

Comment: thanks and im enlightened about your explanation in the occurrence. im a newbie to vba excel and i don't know yet how to loop it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code, the warning will only be triggered if both the ID and the Name exist on the same row. Otherwise, the data will be saved to the sheet.

Be sure to update replace "YourSheetName" with actual name.

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim IDExists As Boolean, NameExists As Boolean

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName") 'Replace with your sheet name

' Find the last row with data in column A
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

IDExists = False
NameExists = False

' Loop through each row to check if both ID and Name exist on the same row
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = idField.Value And ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = nameField.Value Then
        IDExists = True
        NameExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

If IDExists And NameExists Then
    MsgBox "You already have entered this parent."
Else
    'Save to excel sheet
End If
```

Comment: let me try. brb

Comment: `IDExists` and `NameExists` take the same role. Keeping any one as the flag varible is enough.

Comment: this is what i was looking for in catching duplicates for my code. thanks